# Can I add standby namenode into existing Hadoop cluster (with Namenode and Secondary namenode)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I have Hadoop 2.7.2 setup where Namenode and Secondary Namenode node run together with few datanodes. After namenode failure (it was just restart) I realized that Secondary namenode is not redundant namenode as I thought.

So question is, can I make my cluster high available and add Standby namenode without deleting existing metadata from namenode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Zookeeper cluster, but yes, you can add a namenode to [enable High Availability](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html)

Comment: I don't have Zookeeper, will something break if I adjust Nodename so it uses to ZK?

Comment: It's possible, but it's the only way to get a standby namenode